# How can I draw right angled or square end in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I don't know if it's just me but in my Visio normally a line has rounded end as in `1`. 
How can I draw right angled or square end as `2`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I draw right angled or square end?

You need to change the `Cap type`:

> **Add arrows or other line ends to a connector**
>
> You can add arrows, points, or other line ends to a connector.
>
> - Select a connector.
> - Select the Format Sh﻿ape option from the right mouse Action menu. Alternatively, on the Home tab, in the Shape Styles group, select
>   Line, and then select Line Options.
> - In the Format Shape pane, under Line, make sure Solid line is selected, and then select the type, size, or cap type.
> - [image]

You can choose from Round, Square, or Extended.

Source: [Edit connector lines, arrows, or points - Visio](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-connector-lines-arrows-or-points-5669491f-9fce-4676-81f8-ef4553788416)